# How to combine two datasets in R with same number of rows but different columns without any join condition?

Tags: r

Suppose I have two datasets:

d1:

```
    A    B    C
1   0    2    4
2   1    2    3
3   2    1    0
```

d2:

```
    D    E    
1   3    8    
2   1    5    
3   2    7
```

I want to have a data set that is the combination of the two which should look:

```
    A    B    C    D    E
1   0    2    4    3    8
2   1    2    3    1    5
3   2    1    0    2    7
```

I've tried merge but it cross joins them making 3*3.

Comment: It solved. Thank you very much :) MLavoie

Answer (score 5):

We can use `cbind`

```
 do.call(cbind, list(d1, d2))
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
bind_cols(d1, d2)
```